# VBA- Copying a Row without a specific column

Tags: vba, excel

I have a code that will copy a row based on an abbreviation and send it to another excel sheet starting at a certain cell. I need the code to not copy the abbreviation and just the rest of the row. How can I fix my code for it to do this. The column I need excluded is Column A

Table? Data 
[image]

Here is the code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()

Dim c As Range
Dim j As Integer
Dim Source As Worksheet
Dim Target As Worksheet

' Change worksheet designations as needed
Set Source = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set Target = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

j = 11     ' Start copying to row # in target sheet
For Each c In Source.Range("A1:A1000")   ' range of the running log input
    If c = "PP" Then
     Source.Rows(c.Row).Copy Target.Rows(j) ' where i think problem is
       j = j + 1 ' makes it paste to the next open row

    End If
Next c

 j = 30
For Each c In Source.Range("A1:A1000")
    If c = "FA" Then
     Source.Rows(c.Row).Copy Target.Rows(j)
       j = j + 1

    End If
Next c
End Sub
```

Comment: easiest way to me seems to be to delete the cell you don't want after you copy the row.  Other than that you are going to have to loop through all cells in that row and copy them individually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this if you know there are four cells to copy.

```
Source.cells(c.Row,2).resize(,4).Copy Target.cells(j,1)
```

Not sure why you have two loops? Autofilter would be more efficient as you could do away with the loops altogether.